# If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = l$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(\frac1{x^2}) = l$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Suppose that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = l$, $l \in \mathbb R$.
>
> Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(\frac1{x^2}) = l$.

Is it enough for me to say:

Let $g(x) = \frac1{x^2}$.

So, $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = \infty$.

Then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(\frac1{x^2}) = \lim_{g(x) \to \infty}f(g(x)) = l$

Comment: I doubt that's enough. It certainly is true, but you're probably supposed to use the definition.

Comment: That's a good heuristic argument, but depending on the level of rigor expected, you might need to unpack the definitions here.

Comment: e.g. "given any $\epsilon$, $\exists$ $M$ such that if $x > M$, $|f(x) - l|< \epsilon$. Further, since $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \infty$, $\exists \delta$ such that $g(x) > M$ whenever $|x| < \delta$..." etc.